# Reading remote file [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read a remote file using HttpWebRequest in a C# Console Application. But for some reason the request is empty - it never finds the URL.

This is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://uo.neverlandsreborn.org:8000/botticus/status.ecl");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

How come this is not possible?

The file only contains a string. Nothing more!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How are you reading the response data? Does it come back as successful but empty, or is there an error status?

If that doesn't help, try [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org), which will let you see what's happening at the network level.

Also, consider using [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead of `WebRequest` - it does make it incredibly easy when you don't need to do anything sophisticated:

```
string url = "http://uo.neverlandsreborn.org:8000/botticus/status.ecl";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string data = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: ... +1 for introducing me to a new class.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason the server returns a protocol error. This is odd! Same goes for Matthews answer.

Comment: What sort of protocol error? Do you have any details? Have a look with Wireshark to see what it's sending vs what a browser sends.

Comment: Server caused protocol error. Section=ResponseStatusLine Exception at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDateInternal<Uri address, WebRequest request>

Comment: Above was translated from Danish, heres it in english:
The server committed a protocol violation.
Section=ResponseStatusLine Exception at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal<Uri address, WebRequest request>

Comment: The server isn't sending a Content-Length header. Apparently the .NET libraries choke on that, even in explicit HTTP/1.0 mode.

Comment: I came accross: http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000556.html

This worked. Thanks to everyone! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the response stream and read the data out of that. Here's a function I wrote for one project that does just that:

```
    private static string GetUrl(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(url));
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new ServerException("Server returned an error code (" + ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() +
                    ") while trying to retrieve a new key: " + response.StatusDescription);

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should put the response in a using statement too. (I'd also try not to declare variables until the point of first use, on general principle.)

Comment: +1 on two counts... The split definitions was a historical artifact from when I refactored it out to a seperate function after realising I was copy/pasting this code in several places.